# Unix "wrap" filter

Tags: unix, shell, filter

is there one?

something I could use like this:

```
$ cat someFileWithLongLines.txt | wrap -80 --indent|less
```

Comment: thanks for the answers, before posting here I did "man -k wrap" and I completely missed 'fold' :(

Comment: Now we just need `spindle` and `mutilate`.

Comment: @sdg: here's mutilate :P
`echo 'hello world' | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g'|shuf|paste -s -d ''`

Comment: @sdg: Since a spindle pokes holes in a document: `echo "hello world"|sed 's/\(.\)/\1 /g'` or sed `'s/\(.\{40\}\)/\1 /' docfile` or `sed 's/\(.\{8\}\)/\1\t/g docfile' or other variations.

Answer (score 15):

GNU coreutils has a command called `fmt`:

```
$ fmt -40 -t lorem
```

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
   adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
   tempor incididunt ut labore et
   dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
   ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
   exercitation ullamco laboris
   nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
   consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
   in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
   esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
   pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
   cupidatat non proident, sunt in
   culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
   anim id est laborum.
```

Edit: As you can see, `fmt` breaks lines on word boundaries within the given width. Contrast this with the hard boundary of `fold`. The type of indenting that `fmt` does may not be what you're looking for, but you can pipe it (without the `-t` option) through `pr` to get a margin-style indent:

```
fmt -40 lorem | pr -To 6
```

Comment: fold also has the `-s` option, which breaks at spaces instead.

Answer (score 6):

You might want the [`fold`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?fold) command.

```
$ fold -w 80 file.txt
```

or

```
$ cat file.txt | fold
```

Comment: Compared to `fmt` or `columns` `fold` will only add newlines to reach a maximum width (resulting in a mix of short and full-length lines), rather than filling the text neatly to a certain width.

Answer (score 2):

You can indent with [`pr`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?pr), if you like, eg.

```
$ fold -w 76 -s file.txt | pr -T --indent=4
```

Answer (score 1):

The command is called 'fold', but it does not support indenting the wrapped sections of lines. You'll need to bust out awk for that one.

Answer (score 1):

The command is called fold.

$ cat someFileWithLongLines.txt | fold

Answer (score 0):

you can use awk

```
width=10
awk -vw="$width" '{
    i=1
    while( length(substr($0,i,w) ) ){
        print substr($0,i,w)
        i+=w
    }
}' file
```

output:

```
$ more file
this is a line 1
this is a line 2
$ fold -w 10 file
this is a
line 1
this is a
line 2
$ ./shell.sh
this is a
line 1
this is a
line 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is a gnu utility called `columns` (not to be confused with another standard unix command, `column`)

Using a very large width like this can remove wrapping entirely:

```
columns --fill -W 10000 < file.txt
```

(Part of the [autogen package](https://www.gnu.org/software/autogen/manual/html_section/columns-Invocation.html#columns-Invocation).)