# Format wrapped text to indent several spaces when using sed-like utilities in OS X

Tags: macos, unix, sed, formatting

I'm working in the OSX terminal and I'm trying to take text output from a command and format it in such a way that wrapped text lines are indented by several spaces, rather than just being in line with the first character of the beginning of the line:

```
1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
2. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
3. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
```

... would become ...

```
1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
   sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
2. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
   nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
3. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
   cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
```

I've read [this thread on achieving a similar result in unix environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958591/unix-wrap-filter), but it seems as though some of the functionality, as well as options, for the OSX equivalent of those utilities are slightly different.  For full transparency, here's the command that I'm trying to format:

```
curl "http://api.breakingnews.com/api/v1/item/?format=rss"  2>/dev/null | grep -o "<title>[^<]*</title>" | sed -e "s/.*\<title\>\(.*\)\<\/title\>.*/\1/g" | nl -n rz -s " » " -w 2 | fold -s -w 80
```

#### Update

For those interested, here is my final command:

```
curl "http://api.breakingnews.com/api/v1/item/?format=rss"  2>/dev/null | grep -o "<title>[^<]*</title>" | grep -v "<title>Breaking news - breakingnews.com</title>" | sed -e "s/.*\<title\>\(.*\)\<\/title\>.*/\1/g" | nl -n rz -s " » " -w 2 | fold -s -w 80 | awk '!/^[0-9]+\ » / {$0="     "$0}1' | awk '/^[0-9]+\ » / {$0="\n"$0}1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could `awk` be an option?

```
awk '!/^[0-9]+\./ {$0="   "$0}1' file
1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
   sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
2. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
   nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
3. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
   cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
```

---

Here is some to get the raw output, I will look at the format:

```
curl "http://api.breakingnews.com/api/v1/item/?format=rss"  2>/dev/null | awk -v RS="</?title>" 'NR%2==0 && NR>2 {print ++i". "$0}'
```

Comment: It works because `awk` here is reading from a file. Might not work if data is coming in from a pipe. Also the spacing needs to be altered when counts will become > 10 due to extra digit.

Comment: @jaypal Sorry - my apologies with the digits.  I have it padding zeros automatically via `nl`.  @Jotne This worked great with piping it.  In my actual command, I was using `»` instead of a period after each number, so I had to switch that out.  But it worked great. Thanks!

Comment: @jaypal Sorry - updated my comment, as you were commenting.  It worked great after I changed the period to the character I was actually using.  Should have used that in my lorem examples.

Comment: @mbeasley Not a problem. As long as it worked out! `;)`

Answer (score 0):

@Jotne's solutions works great for the case at hand.

Here's a **more generic bash function**:

```bsh
# SYNOPSIS
#     ... | foldIndent [lineWidth indentText]
# DESCRIPTION
#   Format stdin input to be at most LINEWIDTH (default: 80) characters wide
#   and prefix wrapped lines with INDENTTEXT (default: 2 spaces).
#   Note: Uses standard utility `fold`; if no indentation is needed, 
#         use `fold` directly.
# EXAMPLE
#   echo "one two three four" | foldIndent 12 '  '
foldIndent() {
  local width=${1:-80} indent=${2-  }
  (( width-=${#indent} ))
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    fold -s -w $width <<<"$line" | awk 'NR>1 { print "'"$indent"'" $0; next } 1'
  done
}
```

It's a wrapper for `fold` that prefixes wrapped lines with specifiable indentation text.

Here's how to apply it to the OP's command:

```bsh
curl "http://api.breakingnews.com/api/v1/item/?format=rss" 2>/dev/null | 
  grep -o "<title>[^<]*</title>" | sed -e "s/.*\<title\>\(.*\)\<\/title\>.*/\1/g" | 
  nl -n rz -s " » " -w 2 |
  foldIndent 80 '   '
```

---

Further simplification using the [multi-platform web-scraping utility **xidel**](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html):

```bsh
xidel -e '//entry/title' "http://api.breakingnews.com/api/v1/item/?format=rss" |
  nl -n rz -s " » " -w 2 |
  foldIndent 80 '   '
```